# How create a UIScrollView with images?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a `UIScrollView` with images but I see nothing.

```swift
@IBOutlet var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
var imageArray = [UIImageView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainScrollView = UIScrollView()
    var image: UIImage
    image = UIImage(named: "nameImage")!
    var bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageArray  = [bgImage, bgImage,bgImage,bgImage,bgImage]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)

        mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 800)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    self.view.addSubview(mainScrollView)
}
```

What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you considered using Interface builder for your image views? And if the image views are dynamic, have you considered using a `UICollectionView`

Comment: @DavidChopin can you give  your answer please please !!!

Comment: @DavidChopin answer me please

Comment: Have you created an outlet for scrollView? If yes then do not reassign the scrollView object to the scrollView variable 'mainScrollView' if no then use the scrollView initialiser with frame to create your scrollView instead of 'UIScrollView()'

Answer (score 4):

The reason you see nothing is that the scroll view has no size. You have never assigned it a `frame`. So it is a zero-size view at the zero point; it's too small to see.

Comment: Not only is it too small to see, it is not displayed :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the ScrollView with the frame specified:

```
mainScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 100, height:100))//for example
```